# Margins not affecting soundcloud div

Tags: html, css, margin, soundcloud

I'm using divs to create margins on the left and right side of the page. In this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reothenew/g6hk0va5/2/) you can see that this method works for paragraphs but not on a div with soundcloud embeds. In the fiddle I'm using 'padding' instead of 'margin' in order to display the area of the intended margin better.

How can I affect the soundcloud embeds with a margin?

The CSS looks like this:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.left-margin {
float: left;
height: 100vh;
padding-left: 200px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;
}

.right-margin {
float: right;
height: 100vh;
padding-right: 100px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: green;
}

#sc /*soundcloud*/ {
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
max-width: 520px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The margins don't apply to the iframes because you are absolutely positioning them. Make them inside the flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/g6hk0va5/4/

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <p>One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he discovered that in his bed he had been changed into a monstrous verminous bug. He lay on his armour-hard back and saw, as he lifted his head up a little, his brown, arched abdomen divided up into rigid bow-like sections. From this height the blanket, just about ready to slide off completely, could hardly stay in place. His numerous legs, pitifully thin in comparison to the rest of his circumference, flickered helplessly before his eyes.</p>
<iframe width="100%" height="197" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/3829252&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
<iframe width="100%" height="197" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/154829271&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    padding: 0 100px 0 200px;
}
```